# aggregate alertmanager messages as slack threads

Tags: slack, prometheus-alertmanager

Our slack-channel where the alert-manager is posting to is unstructured as you get firing alerts and resolved alerts mixed without them having any relation between them. In addition you cannot really see whether an alert is actually resolved or not.

So I was wondering whether there is a way that alertmanager sends a message to the slack-channel once it is firing, but when it is resolved, the message is sent as a thread message to the initial alert.

Further it would look cool if you could get a reaction to be added to that message, so you can see straight away which ones are resolved.

I think all in all it would look a lot cleaner. But I cannot find anything in that direction so far. So does anybody know how that can be achieved if it is possible at all?